# Jeditable plugins developement

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jeditable

Using Jquery plugin Jeditable to create a form. I have been hacking around trying to combine the charcount plugin and the autogrow from the custom demo page here: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable/custom.html. I'm not clever enough with jquery plugins to figure it out. I am not sure if I can simply have multiple plugins or do I actually need to figure out a way to merge the code? Any pointers?

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the source code for both jedtable-charcounter (http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable/jquery.jeditable.charcounter.js) and jeditable-autogrow (http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable/jquery.jeditable.autogrow.js), you can see that they're basically the same.

I think you can combine like this:

```
    $.editable.addInputType('hybrid', {
        element : function(settings, original) {
            var textarea = $('<textarea />');
            if (settings.rows) {
                textarea.attr('rows', settings.rows);
            } else {
                textarea.height(settings.height);
            }
            if (settings.cols) {
                textarea.attr('cols', settings.cols);
            } else {
                textarea.width(settings.width);
            }
            $(this).append(textarea);
            return(textarea);
        },
        plugin : function(settings, original) {
            $('textarea', this).charCounter(settings.charcounter.characters, settings.charcounter);
            $('textarea', this).autogrow(settings.autogrow);
        }
    });
```

Make sure you reference both plugins.

Then you can call the jQuery like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".hybrid").editable("http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable/php/save.php", { 
      type      : "hybrid",
      submit    : 'OK',
      tooltip   : "Click to edit...",
      onblur    : "ignore",
      charcounter : {
         characters : 60
      },
      autogrow : {
           lineHeight : 16,
           minHeight  : 32
        }
  });
```